# Prevent players from playing my missions

Tags: borderlands-2

I just recently start playing Borderlands 2 online with random people on Steam. I just open up my game to the public and let people play. Some of them are now on my Steam list and they join whenever I am playing.

Yesterday I started TVHM and people joined. After one mission I closed the game, and today when I started the game again I saw that the game is almost halfway done! This is quite annoying because I can not reset the TVHM, just lost lots of levels and fun times.

Is there a way for me to have it so that when I close my game nobody can go on playing?

Comment: Play offline and nobody can join.

Comment: If you quit the game, I'm not understanding how other people can continue *your* game. Are you fully quitting? Or do you just tab out?

Comment: I don't believe Borderlands 2 supports Cloud.

Comment: This doesn't sound normal... are you sure you didn't somehow load an old save from the first play through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When starting a game, the main menu has an option called, "Network Options".  Setting this to "Online Invite Only", or Offline only will ensure that you can play by yourself in peace.

Network Options is also available in your menu after starting, so you can change this on the fly as needed.